# How to select a single field from all records in mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb

I want to do the mongo equivalent of this in SQL :

`select name from student`

Using the c# nugets.

The only examples I can find online are like so

```
var projection = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include("name").Exclude("_id");
var result = collection.Find<BsonDocument>(filter).Project(projection).ToList();
```

However this is equivalent to having a where clause as well which I don't want

`SELECT name from student WHERE status = "A"`

Comment: you should try `var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Empty;
var projection = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include("name");
` then this `var result = collection.Find(filter).Project(projection).ToList();
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Believe that you have defined the filtering rule/criteria in the `filter` variable.

To remove the filter criteria, either assigning it with a *blank* `BsonDocument`.

```cs
BsonDocument filter = new BsonDocument();
```

or working with:

```cs
FilterDefinition<T> filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Empty;
```

which `T` is your entity class.